# Kentico Media Library storage using Azure storage

Tags: azure, kentico

I am analyzing the process to change Kentico Media Libraries to use Azure Storage instead of local file system. The process itself is described in good detail in this [post](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/working-with-physical-files-using-the-api/configuring-file-system-providers/configuring-azure-storage). But, now the question is, what about the existing media? Do i need to execute any procedure to manually upload it, and update all references of each media in the database? Or does Kentico provides any option to migrate the media and update references?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a large undertaking if you have a lot of images on different page types. Also if you're using a simple URL selector as the form control this image paths will need to be updated to use the CDN storage domain and prefix. Assuming you're using workflow, you'll want to write code to check these documents in and out and publish them when you update the URL values.

I just went through this with a client with over 1500 products and each product has between 4 and 9 images each. Plus news articles and resources like PDF and other product images.

My suggestion is to clone the whole environment, perform your configuration changes, update data as needed, then perform your testing. You will find out what will work and what won't very quickly. One "gotcha" is to ensure your CDN is fully configured and replicated before doing your testing. I suggest setting that up in the morning and updating your website configuration in the after or the next day so it has time to replicate.

Comment: Brenden, we have already the Azure CDN configured and being used. I did previously a procedure to update hardcoded URLs on the site content to change from http to https. I end up doing a T-SQL script to update the entries. This code piece that you suggest, would it be using the SDK (with a specific library(es)) or using the Kentico API? Since currently there are many Kentico libraries dedicated to Web projects, i would like to know if it is feasible to consider to create a console app to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: A console app would work, I typically create a blank aspx page and place a button on it to perform a click action.  This action will execute the Kentico API calls.  This way you don't need to worry about adding libraries and such to a console app you'll only use a time or two.

Answer (score 0):

File path to an image is relative (see media_file table), but you need to copy images files yourself. You can do it with [azCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy). Just follow [the documentation on configuring media library storage in azure](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/working-with-physical-files-using-the-api/configuring-file-system-providers/configuring-azure-storage#ConfiguringAzurestorage-ConfiguringKenticotostoreonlymediafilesonAzurestorage) and you will be Ok